# Unsubscribing from, or checking for, the CollectionChanged event via reflection

Tags: c#, events, reflection, observablecollection

I have used reflection in my project to add events to `ObservableCollections` - specifically, `CollectionChanged`. I am able to add the event well enough and there is no problem there. The problem is that the code to add the event is run more than once and so I end up with multiple identical events added in some cases. What I don't know how to do is either check to see if there is already an event assigned, or to remove before I add one (to ensure there is only one event added).

The code is here:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in props)
{
    nType = this.GetPropertyInfoTypeObs(propertyInfo.PropertyType);

    if (nType == Static_Enums.TypeEnums.TYPE_OBSERVABLE_COLLECTION)
    {
        var genargs = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();

        var o = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);

        EventInfo evi = o.GetType().GetEvent("CollectionChanged", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var eventHandler = new Action<object, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
                    (s, a) =>
                    {
                        // Event code here
                        this.MakePropertyDirty(propertyInfo.Name);
                    });

        var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(evi.EventHandlerType, eventHandler.Target, eventHandler.Method);

        evi.AddEventHandler(o, del);
    }
}
```

As stated, this part works fine. But how to handle the issue of the event being added more than once?

I first tried simply having `evi.RemoveEventHandler(o, del)` on the line above. This doesn't work for me - as in, if I watch what happens when that line is executed, the event handler seems to remain untouched. Perhaps I'm doing it incorrectly?

I'd also be happy with a way to check if the event handler already has one assigned, and then skip over adding it again. But how to do that I've no idea.

**Edit**

I have tried creating the delegate as a class property in order that it can persist. But even still, as I trace over the lines, I can see that the handler is not removed when I call the `evi.RemoveEventHandler` with this property delegate.

I then went a little further and tried doing this:

```
EventInfo ef = o.GetType().GetEvent("CollectionChanged");
MethodInfo rem = ef.GetRemoveMethod();
ParameterInfo[] piList = rem.GetParameters();

object[] oList = new object[1];
oList[0] = storedProc;

rem.Invoke(o, oList);
```

Unfortunately it also doesn't seem to do the trick.

Furthermore, I read that in order to remove a handler, it has to be the *exact same* handler in the remove method. Now, in this method here, the derived class has more than one `ObservableCollection`. So I tried limiting the creation of the new delegate (and assigning it to the class property) to only in the case of a particularly named `ObservableCollection` (one I knew would appear). I traced it over again, one line at a time, and the event handler was not removed.

Even if this did work, however, I'd then have to store a delegate for each `ObservableCollection` for which I did this. My god, can't I just tell it to clear the event?

Comment: You have to preserve the delegate you got from `Delegate.CreateDelegate` somewhere. Then you can check later if this paticular delegate instance is already subscribed.

Comment: I can see the code to remove a delegate, using 'RemoveEventHandler', but I didn't see an obvious way to check whether it was already subscribed. Did I miss something in EventInfo?

Comment: You can probably get the invocation list of the underlaying delegate that represents the event. But thats certainly implementation-dependant, like the backing field of properties.